# We are currently looking at circuit and were wondering if this part of the circuit was a DC-DC converter?

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit, dc-dc-converter

[image: Ciruit Board Image]
Looking at a circuit board that is attached to a battery pack that can be used to power home appliances.

Comment: Looks like two dc/dc converters.

Comment: Why is the picture at a 45 degree angle?

Comment: To give the viewer a sense of uneasiness……

Comment: Google the part numbers shown on the IC's.....